# Perform a function at a regular time-based interval with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm currently trying to retrieve the contents of a webpage (JSON) that updates very regularly. Ideally, I would like to download the data from this URL every 10 minutes and save it, appending it to a growing data structure of updates.

**Is there a way to repeatedly run a python function at a user-defined interval (10 minutes)?**

In my case, I'm able to download a url using the below code, but wish to add data to it every 10 minutes.

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
print(data)
```

Comment: Yes, one way is you can use "Cron" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

try crontab to run your py
*/10 * * * * python yourdir/your.py

Comment: This is a very poor answer; you should improve it by providing better explanation on how to precisely use crontab for this case.